# Photos without hijab, can't find the people?

Tags: tawba, hijab, image

There are photos of me without my hijab on people's phones that they took as a group photo or in a crowd or event. It was in the past and they were strangers. At that time I didn't care about photos and wasn't too close to islam as I am now. I can't find these people online and don't know anyone that knows them.

What should I do? Am I going to hell because people (example men) can see me without hijab? I'm so scared.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be punished if you have repented and reformed your ways. And you will not be punished for something which is beyond your control such as the actions of other people. Removing those pictures is their responsibility not yours.

> #### ولا تكسب كل نفس إلا عليها ولا تزر وازرة وزر أخرى
>
> And every soul earns not [blame] except against itself, and no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:164](https://quran.com/6/164?translations=20)</sup>

Also see [Should she ask those who were her friends in the past to remove pictures of her that they have on Facebook?](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/198143/) :

> Rather all she has to do is remove whatever she is able to remove herself.